# Secuirty definion of a ad hoc multi-input functional encryption scheme

Tags: security-definition, functional-encryption, indistinguishability

I have to write an essay on the paper [ad hoc multi-input functional encryption](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2020/11725/pdf/LIPIcs-ITCS-2020-40.pdf), and can't understand the security definition. In a nutshell it is a primitive that  allow sources to supply encrypted data, such that at any point a dynamically-chosen subset of
sources can allow an agreed-upon joint function of their data to be computed by the aggregator.

---

Syntax description:

[image: aMIFE syntax]

---

Security definition:

[image]

---

I've got the following questions about the security definition:

1. I do not understand why a **queried** function is defined and why its defined this way.

I think the gist is a function is queried if you could provide ciphertexts for all it's input arguments (by having the keys when its corrupted  or asking keygen oracle). But what is it trying to say by "for every user associated with it's input wires"?

A function can be calculated on different subset of users. Would it not be more reasonable if it said "$f$ is queried if there exist a  $\{i_1, ... , i_{\ell}\}$ such that for every user  associated with ..."?

2. Should it not read: "$j \in I$, i.e. $j$ is corrupted **and** $y_{j,0} = y_{j,i}$" at the bullet point that I highlighted?

Otherwise whats the point if the inputs that are controlled by the adversary are different? It's not going to help you distinguish the challenge and guess the $b$.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes for the second question you edited "2. Should not it read". My english is not that good but isn't a mistake? is not better use says instead of read?(Just a suggestion)

Comment: Two words were in a bit of a strange order, I think it is OK now.